# Matplotlib: align axes across different figures

Tags: matplotlib

I'm having two different figures with identical figsize which I embed in an latex ducment (picture).
How can I make that it does not missalign slightly in the way it currently is? (the right figure has larger axis)

[image: miss-alligned axes]

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: Keeping the same axes margins should do the trick? For example, `fig = pl.figure()` `fig.subplots_adjust(0.16,0.13,0.97,0.95,0.10,0.35)`. See [matplotlib documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust)

Comment: Don't use `tight_layout`